# Minikube mount is empty

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus).
I am using minikube (v0.18.0) with KVM driver.
I had to mount the host directory to Minikube VM, so they will be accessible to my pod, but the mounted directory is empty.

I am using the below command

```
minikube mount /path/to/host/directory
```

Update: I was using 0.18, updating to 0.19 mount works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using 0.18, updating to 0.19 mount works now

but the correct command is

```
minikube mount /path/to/host/directory:/vmpath
```